# Failed to get resource: alfresco/ibatis/#resource.dialect#/activities-insert-SqlMap.xml

Tags: spring, javabeans, alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm trying to run all-in-one extension of Alfresco. But I got the error below... I don't know if it is a problem of database configuration or other... Can anyone help me?

My repo alfresco-global.properties:

```
dir.root=${alfresco.data.location}

# Alfresco Repo Webapp (alfresco.war) context, ports etc
alfresco.context=alfresco
alfresco.host=localhost
alfresco.port=8080
alfresco.protocol=http

# Alfresco Share Webapp (share.war) context, ports etc
share.context=share
share.host=localhost
share.port=8080
share.protocol=http

# Use Solr4 as that is used by default with Alfresco 5
index.subsystem.name=solr4
solr.host=localhost
solr.port=8080
solr.secureComms=none

# Setting Solr backup for the future. Tweak this if needed (ideally in other env properties files)
solr.backup.alfresco.cronExpression=0 30 2 * * ? 2050
solr.backup.archive.cronExpression=0 30 3 * * ? 2050
solr.backup.alfresco.remoteBackupLocation=${dir.root}/solr4Backup/alfresco
solr.backup.archive.remoteBackupLocation=${dir.root}/solr4Backup/archive

# We are in the local DEV properties file, no need for Solr backup
solr.backup.alfresco.numberToKeep=0
solr.backup.archive.numberToKeep=0

# These jobs seem to require Lucene (Unsupported Operation with Solr) so we disable them / set to future date
# See https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=41597
# If you want to enable them (and so full WQS functionality), please also set index.subsystem.name=lucene
wcmqs.dynamicCollectionProcessor.schedule=0 30 2 * * ? 2060
wcmqs.feedbackProcessor.schedule=0 40 2 * * ? 2060
wcmqs.publishQueueProcessor.schedule=0 50 2 * * ? 2060

# Fail or not when there are node integrity checker errors
integrity.failOnError=true

# Database connection properties
db.driver=${alfresco.db.datasource.class}
db.url=${alfresco.db.url}
db.username=${alfresco.db.username}
db.password=${alfresco.db.password}
db.pool.initial=10
db.pool.max=100
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

# File servers related properties
# For local runs we disable CIFS and FTP
cifs.enabled=false
ftp.enabled=false
```

The error:

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
>   instance of class org.alfresco.web.app.ContextListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer#0'
>   defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'customPropertyEditorRegistrar' while
>   setting bean property 'propertyEditorRegistrars' with key [0]; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'customPropertyEditorRegistrar' defined
>   in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Cannot
>   resolve reference to bean 'NamespaceService' while setting bean
>   property 'namespaceService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dictionaryDAO' defined in class path resource
>   [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'tenantService' while setting bean property 'tenantService'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'tenantService' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/home/patricia/signextension/sign/runner/target/tomcat/webapps/repo/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-repository-5.1.e.jar!/alfresco/mt/mt-context.xml]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tenantAdminDAO' while setting bean
>   property 'tenantAdminDAO'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'tenantAdminDAO' defined in class path
>   resource [alfresco/dao/dao-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'repoSqlSessionTemplate' while setting bean property
>   'sqlSessionTemplate'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'repoSqlSessionTemplate' defined in class path
>   resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'repoSqlSessionFactory' while setting constructor
>   argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'repoSqlSessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse config
>   resource: class path resource
>   [alfresco/ibatis/alfresco-SqlMapConfig.xml]; nested exception is
>   org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper
>   Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException:
>   Failed to get resource:
>   alfresco/ibatis/#resource.dialect#/activities-insert-SqlMap.xml   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:358)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1123)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:676)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
>     at
>   org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderListener.java)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>     at
>   org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderListener.java)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
>     at
>   org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of changes made from 4.2.5.1 you need a new dependency in your maven config:

Add this dependency to your pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.alfresco</groupId>
    <artifactId>alfresco-repository</artifactId>
    <version>{ALFRESCO_VERSION}</version>
    <classifier>h2scripts</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Same error here :(
Where I can find information of new dependencies for new versions of Alfresco? I'm using Alfresco 5.1 community and sdk 2.2.0

Comment: use the dependency for your version?

  <version>5.1.e</version>

https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/#nexus-search;quick~alfresco-repository